# jQuery instant search click on text to select

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery an i'm trying to make an instant search.
Everything works fine when i select the div that contains the key ("result" div), but i need to make it work also when selecting the key within the div(the text from the span with "name" id).
Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = \'search=\'+ searchid;
if(searchid!=\'\')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "searchbrand.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html);
    }
    });
}return false;    
});



jQuery("#result").on("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find(\'.name\').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $(\'#searchid\').val(decoded);
});


jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$(\'#searchid\').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});

</script>



<div class="content2">
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search brand"/>
<div id="result"></div>
</div>';
```

and searchbrand.php...

```
 $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $result = mysql_query("select DISTINCT brand FROM general WHERE brand LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");

$nr=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while( $i<$nr)
     {
      $brand=mysql_result($result,$i,"brand");
          $i++;  
          $b_brand = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';        
          $final_brand = str_ireplace($q, $b_brand, $brand);  

echo'       <div class="show" align="left" >
                <img src="/images/arrow.png" style="height:15px; float:left; margin-right:2px;" /><span class="name">'.$final_brand.'</span>
            </div>';

    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're aiming to achieve. Can you help to clarify?

Comment: @showdev  Now, when i search in the input field, i get the list of suggested terms, but i can select one of them only by clicking the first father div that contains the  text, and i need to be able to select it also when i click on the text.  I have <div><div><span>text...